# completion of functions annoted with @Async

Tags: java, spring-mvc, asynchronous, synchronization

I am calling an async function from a spring-mvc controller.

```
@Async
public void doSomething()
{
    ....
}
```

I am simply calling this function from a controller method

```
@RequestMapping(/person)
@ResponseBody Person returnPerson()
{
    service.doSomething();
}
```

The function returnPerson returns as expected. However I would like to return  `DeferredResult` to denote the completion of returnPerson.

```
@RequestMapping(/person)
@ResponseBody DeferredResult<Person> returnPerson()
{
    service.doSomething();
}
```

I think for that to happen I should know when deSomething has finished its execution so that I can return the response to the caller. I am not getting how do I know when doSomething has finished its execution and then how do I return `DeferredResult` based in that?

Comment: What does your `doSomething` actually do? If it's unrelated and you don't need the results, then it doesn't matter. If you do, it should return a `DeferredResult` or it shouldn't be async.

Comment: doSomething()  uploads a file asynchronously and I just need to return a status response in deferreddresult

Comment: Then return it as some sort of `DeferredResult<StatusResponse>` status from `doSomething()` - you generally only want to do async where you explicitly don't care about the response though.

Answer (score 0):

The @Async annotation method can return a Future object. When you call get on the Future it will block until the @Async method it was returned from finishes.